# How to create a shorter route in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend, controllers, router

Hi so i am wondering how is it possible to create a shorter route other than the usual `helloworld/index/index`.

If I wanted my route to end in `[magentodomain]/helloworld/index` how would I be able to do that?

Comment: I honestly think there is no convenient way to achieve this. `helloworld` refers to the route ID, the first `index` to the controller front name (i.e. the folder the controller file is present) and the second `index` to the controller file which performs the action. This would mean that there needs to be a way to bypass either the controller frontname and directly point to the controller action, which would mean every controller action file needs to have a unique name.

At least this is my thought about it!